# Error en generar PDF en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf

Puedo generar un pdf en el emulador de android studio, pero cuando lo pruebo en un celular físico me sale un error.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "GFG.pdf");

    try {
        pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Archivo PDF generado correctamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error PDF." + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pdfDocument.close();
```

Error: error pdf java.io.filenotfoundexception storage emulated

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que el archivo no existe:

> error pdf java.io.filenotfoundexception storage emulated

pero en realidad el problema es el lugar donde actualmente Android permite crear el archivo, actualmente ya no debes usar `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` , debes usar `getExternalFilesDir()` :

```
//File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "GFG.pdf");
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "GFG.pdf");
```

Comment: getExternalFilesDir me tira este error Cannot resolve method 'getExternalFilesDir'